# Not able to enable Script Authenticator with Keycloak 8.0.1

Tags: keycloak

Not able to enable Script Authenticator with Keycloak 8.0.1.

Tried usinng below option on standalone windows version -

*standalone -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.scripts=enabled*

It does not work. Had used similar option on Keyclaok 7.0, it was working

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

From version 8.x, in order to make your scripts available to Keycloak you need to deploy them to the server in the form of jar.

Refer documentation for details -

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_script_providers